# How to connect Azure Kubernetes Service Pod to Service?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

Trying with Terraform in Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS) to connect 'service' to 'pod' since the Web App doesn't show up. Any idea's how to do it or what is going wrong here?

The namespace and workload have been successfully set up. The created service, however, doesn't seem to connect to the pod. I can open the External URL but the webapp doesn't show up.

Endpoint missing and pod page is empty:
[image]

LoadBalancer setup:
[image]

```json
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    key = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.42.0"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.0.1"
    }
  }
}

# Retrieve AKS cluster information
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster" {
  name                = "kubernetescluster"
  resource_group_name = "myResourceGroup"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.kube_config.0.host

  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "azurevotefront-namespace" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "azurevotefront-annotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "azurevotefront-value"
    }

    name = "azurevotefront-namespace"
  }
}


resource "kubernetes_deployment" "azurevotefront-namespace" {
  metadata {
    name = "azurevotefront"
    namespace = "azurevotefront-namespace"
    labels = {
      app = "AzureVoteFront"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "AzureVoteFront"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "AzureVoteFront"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1"
          name  = "azure-vote-front"

          resources {
            limits = {
              cpu    = "0.5"
              memory = "512Mi"
            }
            requests = {
              cpu    = "250m"
              memory = "50Mi"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


resource "kubernetes_service" "azurevotefront-metadata" {
  metadata {
    name = "azurevotefront"
    namespace = "azurevotefront-namespace"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      App = "AzureVoteFront"
    }
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Labels are case-sensitive. You have `selector = { App = "AzureVoteFront" }` in the service definition which is different to the label you have defined for the Deployment `labels = { app = "AzureVoteFront" }`.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to give an 'Internal Server Error' now. Any idea's where to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I'd probably go with destroy, fix the label, run deploy and see if that changes anything. I've heard that K8s provider can act out from time to time. But if that does not fix it, I would have to dig deeper.

Comment: Oh wait, which port did you specify when opening the URL?